# how to keep randomUUID static

Tags: java, android, static, uuid

I generate the UUID but the problem is that when I close the app and run it again he generate another UUID, I want to generate UUID just for one time, and keep it always the same after installing the application.

```
private final static String androidId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: You should save it to SharedPreference and check if it not generated will create new and store it

Comment: it is not posible is you turn off the app is running, since this variable is static but it belogs to the aplication running. you should persist

Comment: You don't mean 'static', you mean 'persistent'. It already is `static`.

Comment: @CôngHải thank you, It work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference to Công Hải's comment ,I used SharedPreference and it work perfectly:

```
private static String uuid;  


SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
uuid = sPrefs.getString("uuid",null);
if (uuid == null){
      uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
      editor.putString("uuid",uuid);
      editor.apply();
}
```